# Mysql requests. Select from two tables

Tags: mysql

I've done a little MySQL test and there was a question:

> Here's two tables: t1 {t1_id, t1_name}, t2 {t2_id, t1_id, t2_name}.
>   Provide 3 variants of select request from both tables, for t1.t1_id =
>   t2.t1_id, and 3 variants of select requests for t1.t1_id != t2.t1_id

And I really stuck there. I only know one way to select through JOINS which I know is the correct one in most cases. Yet it's just 1 variant. Need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than `JOIN` you can as well use a `Correlated Subquery` and `WHERE EXISTS` with those same condition as in join condition

Using `EXISTS`

```
select * from t1
where exists(select 1 from t2 where t1.t1_id = t1_id);
```

`Correlated Subquery`

```
select * from t1
where t1_id in (select t1_id from t2);
```

Comment: Can you provide at least 1 example of `Correlated Subquery` for this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant for the first case would be to do

```
select * from t1, t2
where t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
```

I think this is called an implicit join or (casually) a comma join. It's implicit because you never use the word JOIN, but you're requiring that those two fields be equal.

Another variant for the second case might be to do

```
select *
from t1 left join t2 on t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
where t2.t1_id is null
```

since this would give you cases where the t2.t1_id is not in table t1.

Comment: I guess JOIN (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER) is one answer anyway, but thanks